# SwiftUI sheet reappears after dismissed on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-watch

I'm developing a fitness app for the Apple Watch that lets you choose an intensity before starting a workout. I want to present the intensity picker before the workout starts, so I tried presenting it as a sheet before navigating to the actual workout view. The problem is that when I try to dismiss the sheet, it is dismissed but it comes right back. I'm using Xcode 14.2 and watchOS 9.1.

This is the main view and also the view that presents the said sheet (the first one, controlled by `showingZonePickerView`):

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Wise_Watch_AppApp: App {
    @StateObject private var workoutManager = WorkoutManager()

    @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                WorkoutView()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $workoutManager.showingZonePickerView, onDismiss: {
                workoutManager.showingZonePickerView = false
            }) {
                WorkoutLevelPickerView(total: 5, completed: 1)
                    .toolbar(.hidden)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $workoutManager.showingSummaryView) {
                SummaryView()
            }
            .environmentObject(workoutManager)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view where the user can pick the preferred workout:

```
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit

struct WorkoutView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutManager: WorkoutManager
    
    @State var linkActive: Bool = false

    var workoutTypes: [HKWorkoutActivityType] = [.cycling, .running, .walking]
    var workoutDictionary: Dictionary<String, HKWorkoutActivityType> = [
        "figure.outdoor.cycle" : .cycling,
        "figure.run" : .running,
        "figure.walk" : .walking
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List(Array(workoutDictionary.keys), id: \.self) { workoutType in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SessionPagingView(),
                tag: workoutDictionary[workoutType]!,
                selection: $workoutManager.selectedWorkout
            ) {
                Label("\(workoutDictionary[workoutType]!.name)", systemImage: workoutType)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding()
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 15, leading: 5, bottom: 15, trailing: 5))
        }
        .listStyle(.carousel)
        .navigationBarTitle("Workouts")
        .onAppear {
            workoutManager.requestAuthorization()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view to which the app navigates when a NavigationLink is pressed:

```
import SwiftUI
import WatchKit
import ConfettiSwiftUI

struct SessionPagingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutManager: WorkoutManager
    @State private var selection: Tab = .metrics
    @State private var counter: Int = 0
    @State private var isViewHidden: Bool = true

    enum Tab {
        case metrics, nowPlaying, milestone
    }

    var body: some View {
        if(isViewHidden) {
            sessionView.hidden()
        } else {
            sessionView
        }
    }
    
    var sessionView: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(workoutManager.tabItems) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text("Congrats!")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .confettiCannon(counter: $counter, num: 40, radius: 200)
                    Text("You just reached")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(.cyan)
                        .tag(Tab.milestone)
                    Text("\(item.value) km")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(.cyan)
                        .tag(Tab.milestone)
                }
                
            }
            MetricsView().tag(Tab.metrics)
            NowPlayingView().tag(Tab.nowPlaying)
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .onAppear {
            workoutManager.showingZonePickerView = true
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.isViewHidden = false
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: workoutManager.running) { _ in
            displayMetricsView()
        }
        .onChange(of: workoutManager.tabItems) { _ in
            if(workoutManager.tabItems.count > 0) {
                displayMilestoneView()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5), execute: {
                    displayMetricsView()
                })
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: self.selection)
    }

    private func displayMetricsView() {
        withAnimation {
            selection = .metrics
        }
    }
    
    private func displayMilestoneView() {
        withAnimation {
            selection = .milestone
            WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.notification)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
                counter += 1
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This is the actual view that I'm presenting inside the sheet:

```
import SwiftUI

struct WorkoutLevelPickerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutManager: WorkoutManager
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    let total: Int
    
    @State var lineWidth: CGFloat = 16
    @State var color: Color = .green
    @State var completed: Double = 1.0
    @State var currentZone: HeartRateZone = zones[0]
    @State var isScrolling: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                CircleLabelView(
                    radius: 30,
                    tracking: 0,
                    size: .init(width: 120, height: 120),
                    text: currentZone.intensity.uppercased()
                )
                .font(.headline)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(currentZone.labelRotationAngleModifier * currentZone.intensity.count / 2)))
                .opacity(isScrolling ? 0 : 1)
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: isScrolling)
                
                WorkoutLevelPickerBackgroundView(total: total, lineWidth: lineWidth)
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    WorkoutLevelPickerProgressView(total: total, completed: Int(completed), lineWidth: lineWidth, zone: currentZone)
                }
                VStack {                    
                    Button {
                        dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: currentZone.iconName)
                            .padding()
                            .font(.title2)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .focusable()
            .digitalCrownRotation(
                detent: $completed.animation(.spring()),
                from: 1.0,
                through: 5.0,
                by: 1.0,
                sensitivity: .low,
                isContinuous: false,
                isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true,
                onChange: { _ in
                    isScrolling = true
                },
                onIdle: {
                    isScrolling = false
                }
            )
            .digitalCrownAccessory(.hidden)
            .onChange(of: completed) {_ in
                if(Int(completed) != currentZone.id) {
                    currentZone = zones[Int(completed) - 1]
                    print(currentZone.tint.description)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is a video of the flow that generates my problem:

[image: Illustration of the problem in the simulator]

I tried presenting the sheet from other views. I also tried dismissing the sheet through a binding, not through the dismiss action. On all these changes, the outcome was the same as before.

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention that, when the sheet is presented, pressing the side button will dismiss it and the app will work as intended until the user tries to start a new workout.

Comment: You are setting `showingZonePickerView` to `true` in your `.onAppear`. When you dismiss that sheet, the `.onAppear` will run again, resetting `showingZonePickerView` back to `true`. I would change your manager so that a `didSet` of `selectedWorkout` sets `showingZonePickerView` to `true`

Comment: You were right! I totally missed the fact that `.onAppear` triggers when the view is showed after a dismissal. I have a `didSet` that does exactly what you said but it was overwritten by `.onAppear`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) mentioned in his comment, the problem was that I was constantly setting `showingZonePickerView` on `true` when the sheet was dismissed and the view reappeared.